# Where do I put logic for when an iOS application hard closes and comes back?

Tags: ios, lifecycle

I have an iOS application where I need to persist a set of data after the application HARD CLOSES (when the user double clicks the Home button and slides the application upwards). Then, when the application comes back to the foreground, I need to fetch that data and do something with it. I'm just not sure where I need to put that logic for Application Hard Close and Resuming the Application.

Comment: Think about what you are asking. How can you possibly save data AFTER the app has been killed? That's impossible. The proper way is to save data when the app enters the background. Then the data will be there when the app is restarted if it gets terminated while in the background.

Comment: That's EXACTLY what I said. But apparently the person who gave me this job said it's possible after a hard close by just using ManagedObjectContext class.

Comment: He just explained it to me. You have to catch the context when it closes with the controllers delegate method called "applicationWillTerminate()"

Comment: According to the Apple docs (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiapplicationdelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationWillTerminate:) there is no guarantee that `applicationWillTerminate:` is called. You need to save your data when entering the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your AppDelegate

When your app is going to be closed, but still in Multitasking menu the following method is getting called

```
-(void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication*)application
```

If after 3 minutes user doesn re-open your app this method is going to be called

```
-(void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication*)application
```

If user re-opens your app from multitasking menu the following method is getting called

```
-(void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication*)application
```

If user is going to close your app from multitasking menu this method is getting called(you will have limited time to perform some logic here)

```
-(void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication*)application
```

Comment: There is no such method as `applicationWillResignTerminate:`.

Comment: Yes it is. Put breakpoints in it and you will see. Xcode's console will not see the NSLog calls in the scope of `applicationWillTerminate`

Answer (score 0):

When user presses home twice `applicationWillResignActive` and `applicationDidEnterBackground` is called. You can save data here.

When user opens app, `applicationWillEnterForeground` is called, you get data which you save and process.

Comment: This is for a soft close. I'm looking for when I hard close the application, which is on applicationWillTerminate(). But thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When a user hard-closes the application, the UIViewController's Delegate's method called    `applicationWillTerminate`. Here I can catch and save the model data before it's all destroyed.

Then when a user launches the application again, there are many choices like `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` where I can grab the data stored to disk.

Comment: Yes it is. Just tested it. NSLog won't work in its scope though because the app is not in the foreground so it seems like its not calling `applicationWillTerminate`, but if you put breakpoints there you'll see that it is. Please upvote my answer.

Comment: Well what do you know. This changed at some point because this was not always the case.

Answer (score -1):

Your app no longer gets an applicationWillTerminate call ever. You are simply silently killed while in the background. You have to write your app to save state in the applicationDidEnterBackground handler, as nmh describes. That's your only option.

Comment: applicationWillTerminate is confirmed running everytime I hard close. So that's not actually true.

Comment: Ok, I guess I overstated it to say never. However, you cannot depend on it being called. The normal course of events now is for your app to move to the background, and then be silently killed when the system needs the memory.

Comment: As quoted from the document- "For apps that do not support background execution or are linked against iOS 3.x or earlier, this method is always called when the user quits the app". So this is fine as I'm only worrying about iOS 7.

Comment: uh, no. For iOS 3 and earlier, you would always get an applicationWillTerminate message. In 4.0 and later, you usually don't get such a call.